# ReSharper formatting: disable remove spaces for anonymous object creation

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm not sure if my title is entire accurate, however, I would like to disable the feature in ReSharper formatting where it removes spaces upon formatting. The following image describes the behaviour (red = before format, green = after format)

:
[image: ReSharper formatting]

As you can see the spaces before `id` and after `fileId` are removed, so:

`new { id = fileId }` --> 
`new {id = fileId}`

I would like to disable this behaviour, and actually (if possible) enforce the leading and trailing space. I can't find what the option is called in the ReSharper -> Options -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Spaces tab.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can change this in the settings so it actually adds those spaces if missing

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The problem is I don't know what the setting is called.

Comment: Wanted to look for you but I don't have it installed. Ill get back to you in a minute if no one else has responded :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the spacing with the option: `Within single-line initializer braces`.
It can be found here: 
*Resharper -> Options -> Code editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Spaces*
[image]

Comment: Thanks this was indeed exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Is there a way to have ReSharper ENFORCE these rules rather than have them as preferences? I know on typing ReSharper will arrange things based on the preferences but what about existing code? And I really don't want to run cleanup code on everything, I just want whitespacing issues to appear in the inspection results?

Comment: @BGTurner I actually don't really know, I don't use ReSharper anymore else I would'v looked into it for you. I looked on the website but could not find a way to set it to show formatting issues in the inspection results. I hope you find it, good luck!